# Calculate a confidence interval of 88% for the difference in proportions

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

A survey of 400 men and 400 women in a certain city showed that 270 men and 240 women favor a certain proposition. Calculate a confidence interval of 88% for the difference in proportions between men and women. Interpreting the result.

**My attempt:**

By hypothesis we know:

$N_x=400$
$N_y=400$
$n_x=270$
$n_y=240$

Note $\bar{p}(x)=\frac{270}{400}=0.675$ and $\bar{p}(y)=\frac{240}{400}=0.6$

Let $1-\alpha=0.88$ then $\frac{\alpha}{2}=0.06$

We know the confidence interval have the form

$$p=(p_1,p_2)$$

where
$$p_1=(\bar{p}(x)-\bar{p}(y))-\phi_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\bar{p}(x)(1-\bar{p}(x))(N_x-n_x)}{n_x(N_x-1)}+\frac{\bar{p}(y)(1-\bar{p}(y))(N_y-n_y)}{n_y(N_y-1)}}$$

$$p_2=(\bar{p}(x)-\bar{p}(y))+\phi_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\bar{p}(x)(1-\bar{p}(x))(N_x-n_x)}{n_x(N_x-1)}+\frac{\bar{p}(y)(1-\bar{p}(y))(N_y-n_y)}{n_y(N_y-1)}}$$

Note $\phi_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=1.56$

Then $p_1=-0.4096$ and $p_2=0.5596$

Here i'm stuck because $p_1>0$ but i have $p_1<0$. Can someone help me?

Comment: Where did $N_x−n_x$ come from? finite population? Obviously, this question is not for finite population, because no population size is given. It seems the CI should be from 0% to 15%

Comment: Use [Fisher exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) or similar test for difference of proportions with matching test for [confidence intervals](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19948745).

Comment: I suggest you ignore the suggestion by @Carl, because it will not advance your progress in this problem. Instead, you would learn far more by reviewing the underlying theory behind the t-test, with special focus on understanding distinctions between *population, sample,* and *outcomes.* Your problem is that you have selected an incorrect set of formulas and just plugged in the numbers. Although that strategy can help you succeed in passing a course, it usually doesn't work in helping you learn and understand.

Comment: @whuber Fine ignore my comment. OP asked for "the difference in proportions" and your answer is $t$-testing? You lost me there.

Comment: Your interval seems to be symmetric about the observed difference so what do you feel is the problem?

Comment: @Carl: I agree with whuber that, given the level of the question the OP's struggling with, they'd be better off reviewing the basic statistical concepts associated with e.g. t-tests rather than going down the rabbit holes of exact conditional tests & confidence intervals for parameters of discrete distributions. Your links do provide interesting reading for more advanced students (but note that Fay's paper concerns odds ratios rather than differences in proportions).

Comment: See [Understanding the formula for the Confidence Interval of the difference between two sample proportions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/225387/17230) for an intuitive explanation of how to calculate a Wald confidence interval.

Comment: @Scortchi Thanks for the tip. In which case, you have found a duplicate question.

Comment: @Carl, Yes, thanks (don't know why I didn't think to close as a duplicate). BTW, if you liked Fay's paper, you might be interested in [Thulin & Zwanzig (2017), *Bernoulli*, **23**, 1, "Exact confidence intervals and hypothesis tests for parameters of discrete distributions"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.0442.pdf).

Comment: @Scortchi Thanks, for the paper read. Reviewing is a pleasure when constructive, and we all see different things, whence all the comments here, even for a straight forward question.

Comment: @Carl: You're welcome. The wonderfully counter-intuitive examples are for binomial & Poisson distributions, but the arguments apply just as much to Fisher's non-central hypergeometric distribution.